# Teradata TPT performance

Tags: teradata, informatica, informatica-powercenter

Can anyone tell me what is the maximum possible throughput of Teradata Parallel Transporter via using Informatica.

I am using Informatica TPT connection to load a huge flat file (around 10 to 15 Gb) in a table which has CANSE_N partitioning. 
I am getting a throughput of aroud 50,000 to 56,000 Rows/sec and i am looking for a performance of more than 90,000 rows/sec please suggest as performance am getting is not enough to load such big files.

Thanks.

Comment: How many rows in your source file? How many sessions are allocated for TPT?

Comment: Are you loading to/from SSD or spinning disk? Are you running 1Gb or 10Gb ethernet between Teradata and Informatica? What else is running on Teradata when you are loading? Which TPT operator are you using? Is the target table empty? Is the target table SET or MULTISET? Does the target table have a UPI or USI to eliminate duplicate row checking if the table is defined as SET?

Answer (score -2):

MLoad (update) is the operator. Source is MQ from Webshpere. One box with 20GB and 2 2.9 GHz CPU's (QA). millions in the source.